# What does "it" in "it be" refer to?

Tags: dune, dune-2021

In Dune (2021), Paul and Gurney had sword fight with a shield devices.
Paul believes that he defeated Gurney in the fight but Gurney says:

> Gurney: But look down, my lord. You'd have joined me in death.
> I see you found the mood.
>
> Paul: Will **it** be that bad?
>
> Gurney: You don't get it, do you?

What does "it" in "it be" refer to?

Comment: He is referring to the upcoming move to Arrakis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The rest of Gurney's reply to Paul:

> You don’t get it, do you? You don’t really understand the grave nature of what’s happening to us. For 80 years Arrakis belonged to House Harkonnen. Eighty years of owning the spice fields. Can you imagine the wealth? In your eyes, I need to see it in your eyes. You never met Harkonnens before. I have. They are not human. They’re brutal! You have to be ready.

"It" is the coming future - the Harkonnens have a longstanding vendetta against the Atreides, and have just been ousted from an incredibly profitable fiefdom of Arrakis to be replaced by their blood enemies.

House Atreides - including Leto and his senior council (which includes Gurney) fully expect there to be retaliation.

> They just underestimate the full extent of it.